# How to differentiate whether a page is requested from a link or a redirect?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a kiosk web application. A user can click on a link that will bring him to a video gallery. I also have a timer that redirects to the same video gallery if there is no activity for one minute. If the page was redirected due to inactivity, I want to automatically play a random video from the video gallery.

Currently I use the query string to differentiate how the video gallery was requested (i.e. the link will request for http://localhost/video whereas the redirect due to inactivity will request for http://localhost/video?isredirect=true)

From then on, I use javascript to parse the url and retrieve the value of isredirect as a condition to automatically play a random video or not.

Is this the right way?

Comment: It's fine. There is no one right way.

Comment: That's how I would have done it, query string.